# How to not have Gradle quit Scala's REPL immediately?

Tags: scala, gradle, read-eval-print-loop

These simple lines in `build.gradle` expose a `repl` task that would ideally fire up a scala REPL. Fire up and keep alive that is. After the repl loads, it immediately receives a :quit command and exits.

Important parts of `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies{
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7"
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.11.7"
}

task repl(type:JavaExec) {
  main = "scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner"
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Launching the REPL:

```
% gradle repl
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileScala UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:repl
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (OpenJDK Server VM, Java 1.7.0_91).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :quit

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 31.177 secs
```

REPL quits automatically immediately after launching. How to not have the REPL quit immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to redirect console input to your javaexec java process. Try adding `standardInput System.in` to your task definition. In my case, I also found it necessary to add `args '-userjavacp'`.

```
task repl(type:JavaExec) {
  main = "scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner"
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  standardInput System.in
  args '-usejavacp'
}
```

and finally running gradle with the `-q` option suppresses the gradle progress prompts giving me a cleaner scala repl.

Comment: Cheers, that worked. As you were saying, without the `-q` option gradle's prompt intrudes on the REPL's prompt. However, I discovered that the `--console plain` option is more fitting: it liberates the repl like `-q`, and makes readline behave better. Without `--console plain` I had to use rlwrap for backspace and history to work. I have posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35632085/scala-repl-in-gradle) and will try to outline these things there.