# Scala REPL in Gradle

Tags: scala, gradle, classpath, read-eval-print-loop

At the moment Gradle's scala integration does not offer REPL functionality. How to ergonomically run a Scala REPL from Gradle with the appropriate classpath?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Minimal `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

repositories{
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
  compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7"
  compile "org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.11.7"
}

task repl(type:JavaExec) {
  main = "scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner"
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  standardInput System.in
  args '-usejavacp'
}
```

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35617909/1714997) for explaining how to direct stdin with standardInput and have REPL use the right classpath with args.

Notice the `scala-compiler` library is a dependency. That's where `scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner` is found.

From the console a number of options are needed to run the REPL:

- `--no-daemon`, if you are using a Gradle daemon. At the moment, the REPL does not respond to keystrokes if run from the daemon.
- `--console plain`. A popular, but inferior alternative is `--quiet`. If run without one of these options, REPL's prompt is contaminated by Gradle's progress report. `--console plain` has the advantage that it also adjusts readline's behaviour so that `rlwrap` is unnecessary.

Full command to run the REPL is `gradle repl --console plain --no-daemon`, so creating an alias in your shell makes sense.

Comment: it works, but I'm not able to go to the previous command with a key up. may be you know how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not using Gradle at this time, but off the top of my head you might try using rlwrap with `--quiet` instead of `--console plain`.