# gradle REPL in java8 for scala development

Tags: java, scala, gradle, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a way to retrofit java8 with a REPL in gradle similar to `sbt console` which automatically adds the classes of the project to the class path of the REPL? https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/net.java.openjdk.shinyafox.jshell.gradle.plugin only is applicable for java9 or is the workaround of [Scala REPL in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35632085/scala-repl-in-gradle) considered still best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following along with http://geekplace.eu/flow/posts/2017-09-28-how-to-add-a-repl.html

my `build.gradle.kts` looks like:

```
plugins {
    scala
}

dependencies {
    compile(project(":core"))
    compile(Conf.plugins.ammonite)
}

tasks{
    "printClasspath"{
        dependsOn("assemble")
        doLast{
            println(java.sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath.asPath)

        }
    }
}
```